# Как получить первые 15 элементов из Базы данных postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, gino

Я использую библиотеку gino для работы с postgresql.
Не понимаю какой нужно сделать запрос чтобы получить первые 15 элементов из базы данных.
Пример кода:

```
async def get_product():
items = await Product.query.gino()[:15]
return items
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так

```py
items = await Product.query.limit(15).gino.all()
```